# C++: Why is there std::getenv but no std::setenv?

Tags: c++, setenv

The C++ standard has [std::getenv](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv), but I have to fallback to C's `setenv` (and be hit with deprecation warnings for including <stdlib.h>).

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Maybe because you can do that through std::system?

Comment: @PepijnKramer so why was `getenv` standardised?

Comment: @PepijnKramer no, `std::system` will run the command in a subshell so it can't change the current shell

Comment: @phuclv Ofcourse *doh* ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a reason for this?

`setenv()` is operating system specific POSIX function. It's not part of the C programming language standard, so it's not imported in C++ in std:: namespace.

Comment: Isn't it exactly as OS-specific as `getenv`?

Comment: Well, it seems it is not.  Simple example, there is `getenv` on windows, but no `setenv`. (I know nothing about windows, just googled it)

Comment: Windows has [`_putenv()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/putenv-wputenv?view=msvc-170) instead. The question asks about "why wasn't setenv standardized", which you don't answer.

Comment: and POSIX also has [`putenv()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/putenv.3.html)